# Google Apps Script - Setting a row to complete only after it's been ran through the loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have Google Apps Script which inputs events into my google calendar from a spreadsheet. Anyone know how to have the script set a row's background color to green & last column value to "complete" only if it's been ran through the loop?

Currently I have it just setting the full range to these parameters, but would like to prevent certain rows from being included if the last column is equal to "Invalid".

```
function inputEvents() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("B1").getValue();
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId)
  var lr = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
  var count = spreadsheet.getRange("A3:AF"+lr+"").getValues();

  for (x=0; x<count.length; x++) {

    var events = count[x]; 

    var name = events[2];
    var phone = events[3];
    var email = events[4];
    var title = events[5];
    var startTime = events[6];
    var endTime = events[7];
    var description = events[8];
    var location = events[9];
    var eventId = events[31];
    var contactHeader = "CONTACT:";
    var descriptionHeader = "DESCRIPTION:";
    var complete = "Complete";
    var invalid = "Invalid";

    var info = 
    contactHeader.bold() + "\n" 
    + name + "\n" 
    + phone + "\n" 
    + email + "\n" 
    + "\n" + descriptionHeader.bold() + "\n" 
    + description;

    var options = {
      'guests' : email,
      'description': info,
      'sendInvites': 'True',
      'location': location,
       }

    if (eventId != complete && eventId != invalid){
      calendar.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, options);
      spreadsheet.getRange("AF3:AF"+lr+"").activate().setValue('Complete');
      spreadsheet.getRange("A3:AF"+lr+"").activate().setBackground('#d9ead3');   
    }
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the `setValue` and `setBackground` methods to the entire range, you need to apply them only to the range you're interested in, try setting a `currentRow` variable and change the range you're getting inside your `if` statement, like this:

```
var currentRow = 3 + x;
if (eventId != complete && eventId != invalid){
  calendar.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, options);
  spreadsheet.getRange("AF" + currentRow).setValue('Complete');
  spreadsheet.getRange("A"+ currentRow + ":AF" + currentRow).setBackground('#d9ead3');   
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked, makes sense, and is a simple solution.I appreciate your help!